# Firebase deep query in Swift, with 3 unknown node names of the reference path - is it possible?

Tags: swift, firebase

I have had several hundreds of players play a game I created, and each team's score is located down this path on my firebase structure:

myref.firebaseio.com/UK/***date here***/Tournaments/***time here***/***player name here***/Final Score

The last key is "Final Score", followed by the team's score as the value.

The problem is that the *date here*, *time here*, and *player name here* nodes are different depending on the day and time the game was played and the name the player chose.

**I want to simply extract each score from all the players and add them in an array, in order to calculate the average.**

I am looking for a way to tell the query "find me a "Final Score" key, several sub nodes down, 3 of them with unknown names, and get me the value. Do this for all entries in the database"

I have managed to go 1 level down with an unknown path , but no more than 1 level.

Reading about deep queries did not help me. Is it possible to do this, or I will have to change my database structure to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2):

On Firebase Realtime Database a query can contain only one unknown level. In other words, a query operations on a list of nodes, not on a tree of nodes. If you have multiple nested level, you will need to find a different way to search it. That can either be client-side (for small sets of data), or by storing a flat list with the information you want to query.

In your case the latter would be a flat list of "final score" values, regardless of their date and time.

Also see:

- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)

Comment: That was my suspicion also Frank - i will be going for the flat list solution going forward. Many thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

You need to do loop over all unknown values to get finalscore .. something like this

```
 ref.child("UK").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snap) in
            let dates  = snap.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
            for date in dates{ // To get all Unknown dates
                let tournmentSnap = date.childSnapshot(forPath: "Tournaments").children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
                for unkownTime in tournmentSnap{  // To get all Unknown Time
                    let playerSnap = unkownTime.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
                    for play in playerSnap{ // To get all Unknown Players
                        print(play.value) // Final Score
                    }
                }
```